# Page loading icon when some one click a drop-down nav item on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a index page which is loading pretty fast, no issues in it. On that page i have a drop down nav items called 2018. And once clicked on it the drop down will display the months. Wehn users click a particular month, the time it takes to load the page is longer. i wanted to keep a "Page loading icon" at the center. That icon should be there until the page loads comletely.
Below is my sample code for drop down and i want to have a page loading once each nav item is clicked.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="menu" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        2018
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="atab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">January</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="btab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">February</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="btab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">March</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="dtab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">April</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="etab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">May</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="ftab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">June</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="gtab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">July</a>
      </div>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

I have this loader script below to display loading icon when my index page loads. But i dont know how to use this when my drop down nav item is clicked.

```
<div id="loader"></div>
<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
</div>
```

Much appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

code pen not working properly so i write done complete code for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <style>

        #loader {
            position: fixed;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            z-index: 999999;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
            border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: #f3f3f3;
            /*border-top: 16px solid #3498db;*/
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;

        }

  </style>
 </head>
<body>

<img id="loader" src="https://intelligencedespatrimoines.fr/ipat2/wp-content/plugins/gallery-by-supsystic/src/GridGallery/Galleries/assets/img/loading.gif" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="menu" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        2018
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="atab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">January</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="btab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">February</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="btab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">March</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="dtab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">April</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="etab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">May</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="ftab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">June</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a> <a class="gtab" href="#" data-toggle = "tab">July</a>
      </div>
    </li> 
</ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#loader").hide();
        $(".atab").click(function(){
            $("#loader").show();
        });
    });
  $(document).load(function () {
        $("#loader").show();
   });</script>
</body>
</html>
```

add link a="#" for good result

Comment: @ Anil,Thanks first for your time to mention the code. I see couple of issues. 1) My actual code which i have with my CSS to run the loading icon failed to run on my home page. So i could achieve bringing up a loading icon which will be shown till the page is loaded. Once after that it will be stopped. 2) Your code works fine, but once i used your code on the script, I see loading icon even after the tab contents are displayed. I mean once i click on January dropdown, dashboard for january comes up in 5 secs and even after the page has been displayed still the loading Icon keeps running

Comment: @SSS you add script to every page or your main master page

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with an animated image use pure code. Just display this whenever it is needed.

[spin.js](https://spin.js.org/)

The example on this page has the javascript to activate it. Add an event to your dropdown good to go.

Answer (score 0):

**css**

```
<style>
        #loader {
            position: fixed;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            z-index: 999999;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
            border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: #f3f3f3;
            /*border-top: 16px solid #3498db;*/
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
        }
    </style>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).load(function () {
        $("#loader").show();
        });
       $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#loader").hide();
                $(".atab").click(function () {
                    $("#loader").show();
                });
            });
```

**html**

```
<img id="loader" src="loading.gif" />
```

its working for me

Comment: thanks for your code but i'm not getting it right. Would you mind explaining it in a codepen?